# getting issue when download the apache-airflow using docker

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, airflow

```
doc-postgres-1           | selecting default max_connections ... 100
doc-postgres-1           | selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
doc-postgres-1           | selecting default time zone ... Etc/UTC
doc-postgres-1           | creating configuration files ... ok
doc-postgres-1           | running bootstrap script ... 2022-11-17 08:18:14.665 UTC [47] LOG:  could not link file "pg_wal/xlogtemp.47" to "pg_wal/000000010000000000000001": Permission denied
doc-postgres-1           | 2022-11-17 08:18:14.674 UTC [47] FATAL:  could not open file "pg_wal/000000010000000000000001": No such file or directory
doc-postgres-1           | child process exited with exit code 1
doc-postgres-1           | initdb: removing contents of data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data"
doc-postgres-1 exited with code 4294967295
doc-postgres-1           | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
doc-postgres-1           | This user must also own the server process.
doc-postgres-1           |
doc-postgres-1           | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
doc-postgres-1           | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
doc-postgres-1           | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
doc-postgres-1           |
doc-postgres-1           | Data page checksums are disabled.
doc-postgres-1           |
doc-postgres-1           | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
doc-postgres-1           | creating subdirectories ... ok
doc-postgres-1           | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
doc-postgres-1           | selecting default max_connections ... 100
doc-postgres-1           | selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
doc-postgres-1           | selecting default time zone ... Etc/UTC
doc-postgres-1           | creating configuration files ... ok
doc-postgres-1           | running bootstrap script ... 2022-11-17 08:18:25.475 UTC [42] LOG:  could not link file "pg_wal/xlogtemp.42" to "pg_wal/000000010000000000000001": Permission denied
doc-postgres-1           | 2022-11-17 08:18:25.489 UTC [42] FATAL:  could not open file "pg_wal/000000010000000000000001": No such file or directory
doc-postgres-1           | child process exited with exit code 1
doc-postgres-1           | initdb: removing contents of data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data"
container for service "postgres" is unhealthy
```

not able to solve this issue "FATAL:  could not open file "pg_wal/000000010000000000000001": No such file or directory"

i want to use airflow on container

Comment: Hard to say with what little information you've included.  It's important to know what type of computer you're on, what command(s) you're running to get here, how to reproduce, etc.

Comment: Can you add the docker compose file you are using? and what is the os of your computer? (linux or mac os)